# why do we need to sometime jitter the data when using correlation (Spearman) in R

Tags: r, correlation, spearman-rho

For some reason when I am computing the spearman,

```
cor.test(data$ag, data$co, method = "spearman")
```

it gives me a warning

> Warning message: In cor.test.default(data\$ag, data\$co, method =
>   "spearman") :   Cannot compute exact p-value with ties

I googled and people suggested to jitter the data:

```
ag.jitter <- jitter(data$ag)
co.jitter <- jitter(data$co)
```

And now it works without any warning. I wonder what could cause the first warning?

```
cor.test(ag.jitter, co.jitter, method = "spearman")
```

Comment: Who suggested to jitter your data? What justification did they give? I would just use `exact = FALSE` or instead use Kendall's tau (`method = "kendall"`).

Comment: The warning is caused by the fact that you have ties in your data and Spearman is a correlation based on the ranks of the data; the ties imply there is not a unique ordering, and therefore ranking, of the data, among other things.  `cor.test.default` does not calculate an exact p-value in this case.

Comment: Try calculating a p-value several times on the sane data using jittering each time. What do you notice?   ... If you do it a large number of times, what do you notice about the average correlation after jittering?

Answer (score 2):

In general, in my opinion, modifying your data to use a statistical test with restrictive assumptions (in this case, no ties) is not advisable when an equivalent non-restrictive statistical method exists. Using a Spearman correlation test without an exact p-value, or using Kendall's $\tau$ in place of Spearman's $\rho$ are both valid approaches for data with ties.

As the simulation below illustrates, jittering data can induce fairly large changes in the observed p-values. Using a non-exact correlation test or Kendall's $\tau$ produce more sensible results.

```r
x <- rnorm(1000, sd = 0.1)
x[1:100] <- x[1]
y <- x + rnorm(1000, sd = 1)
y[200:300] <- y[200]

plot(x, y)
```

[image]

```r
cor.test(x, y, method = "spearman")
#> Warning in cor.test.default(x, y, method = "spearman"): Cannot compute exact p-
#> value with ties
#> 
#>  Spearman's rank correlation rho
#> 
#> data:  x and y
#> S = 152678660, p-value = 0.007922
#> alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
#> sample estimates:
#>        rho 
#> 0.08392713


pvals <- replicate(1000, 
  cor.test(
    jitter(x),
    jitter(y),
    method = "spearman")$p.value
)

hist(pvals, breaks = "FD")
```

[image]

```r
cor.test(x, y, method = "spearman", exact = FALSE)
#> 
#>  Spearman's rank correlation rho
#> 
#> data:  x and y
#> S = 152678660, p-value = 0.007922
#> alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
#> sample estimates:
#>        rho 
#> 0.08392713
cor.test(x, y, method = "kendall")
#> 
#>  Kendall's rank correlation tau
#> 
#> data:  x and y
#> z = 2.6233, p-value = 0.008709
#> alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
#> sample estimates:
#>        tau 
#> 0.05590293
```